# Linker script confusion - why multiple labels are needed?

Tags: linker, linker-scripts

Hello I have a "linker script" for GNU linker `ld` and I have two questions related to it:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-bigarm", "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
ENTRY(__start)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x11029000;

    .text :
    {
        __exidx_start = .;
        PROVIDE (__gnu_textstart = .);
        startup.o(.text .text.*)
        *(.text .text.*)
    }

    .rodata : 
    { 
        *(.rodata .rodata.*); 
    }

    __exidx_end = .;
    PROVIDE (__gnu_textend = .);

    .data :
    {
        PROVIDE (__gnu_datastart = .);
        *(.data .data.*); 
        PROVIDE (__gnu_dataend = .);
    }

    .bss :
    {
        PROVIDE (__gnu_bssstart = .);
        *(.bss .bss.*) *(COMMON); 
        PROVIDE (__gnu_bssend = .);
    }

    PROVIDE (end = .);
    PROVIDE (__end = .);
    __image_size = ((__gnu_bssstart - __gnu_textstart) + 511) & ~ 511;
    __EH_FRAME_BEGIN__ = 0;

}
```

**Q1:** Why do we define multiple labels like `__exidx_start` and `__gnu_textstart` for the same adress? The later is defined using `PROVIDE`.

**Q2:** At the end the linker script calculates the image size like this:

```
__image_size = ((__gnu_bssstart - __gnu_textstart) + 511) & ~ 511;
```

Would we get the same result if we calculated it like this:

```
__image_size = ((__exdix_start - __exidx_end) + 511) & ~ 511;
```

Comment: I think both are specified since your program start address and your text section both need to be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.10/ld_3.html#SEC17 it looks like using the PROVIDE command is meant as a declaration ONLY IF used without another declaration.  The benefit being that the symbol could be defined by a user should they choose (or if they are just not aware of the symbol).  In a sense, the definition in the PROVIDE will act as a default of sorts if it is never defined elsewhere but still referenced.

Given that, I would assume that `__gnu_textstart` is meant to be an alias of sorts to `__exidx_start` and therefore that the answer to ***Q2*** is yes, as the symbols reference the same locations.

Comment: They are the same address, but there is a different connotation by them.  `__gnu_textstart` is where code starts.  `__exidx_start` is an 'exception index' table may refer.  Similarily, `__gnu_textend ` is where 'code' ends and defined as where exception indexes end.  If you were to move to a 'rom/flash' system then these values might not be the same.  For a system that loads to RAM, then they are the same.  The underlying code can work with either type of system if two labels exist.